# how to send json response in Restapi in object oriented php

Tags: php

Hey there i am trying to build **`JSON`** restful API using object oriented PHP.
My question is how do you send `JSON` response in this scenario

here is my code

```
if($post->update()) {
  echo 
    array('message' => 'Post updated')
} else {
  echo
    array('message' => 'Post not updated')
}
```

Comment: Hi @alex could you please add the rest of your code? Do you already have a connection to wherever you want to send the json string? A start would be `json_encode()`. This returns a json string. http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap your array in json_encode

```
if($post->update()) {
  echo json_encode(
    array('message' => 'Post updated')
  );
} else {
  echo json_decode(
    array('message' => 'Post not updated')
  );
}
```